# How do I add a method to return "variables" in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In Java, variables in a class are usually private so external classes access them through accessor and mutator methods. This lets one change the method in one place so all other code that accesses it gets changed too.

In Rails, code usually accesses an item's data directly. Is there a way to add a method so all code that was accessing the data directly now accesses it through the method?

**Example**
Given `person = Person.first`, `person.name` returns the name of a Person in Rails, e.g. "Jack". Let's say I wanted every person.name to return a title with the name, such as "Dr.". What should I do to the Person Model to do this? Can I just add a `name` method? How would it know which `name` was being called?

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base

  #method to change what name returns

end
```

Comment: This isn't a direct answer to your question, but if you are wanting to perform these sorts of augmentations of model data for presentation, consider adding a ViewModel/Decorator implementation like [Draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper) to your stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ruby exists several "methods" that creates getters and setters like in Java.

```
attr_accessor :name # creates getter and setter for @name variable.
attr_reader :name   # creates getter for @name variable.
attr_writer :name   # creates setter for @name variable.
```

For example, the code of `attr_accessor :name` is equivalent to these methods

```
def name # getter
  @name
end

def name=(value) #  setter
  @name = value
end
```

And of course you can modify your getter or setter to your convenience

```
def name
  "Dr. #{@name}"
end
```

In Rails ActiveRecord models you have to use this syntax to create manually an attribute accessor.

```
def name
  self[:name]
end

def name=(value)
  self[:name] = value
end
```

Comment: This code will return nil when added to a rails model:
 

    `def name  
      @name
    end`

Comment: I clarify the answer for Ruby (a class) vs Rails (ActiveRecord model).

Answer (score 1):

> Person.name returns the name of a Person in Rails, e.g. "Jack". Let's say I wanted every Person.name to return a title with the name, such as "Dr.". What should I do to the Person Model to do this? Can I just add a name method?

You can use `attr_accessor`. This method creates `reader` and `writer`. You can also explicitly creates this methods. The instance variable inside inside the model are accessible with `self` keyword. It is basically a placeholder of its model object. So when you do `self.name` it means means that `user.name` for `User` model.

The case which you above mentioned where you have name which has value "Jack"  and you want to modified that to "Dr. Jack". Ideally you you either have to use `before_save` or `before_update` callback. Or, you use `virtual attributes` concept. Example

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name_without_title

  def name
    'Dr. ' + self.name_without_title
  end
end
```

> How would it know which name was being called?

When you call some model like

```
user = User.find 1
user.name_without_title = 'Jack'
user.name // returns 'Dr. Jack'
```

The `name` is not a class method. It is only accessible when you have `User` model object.  In model, `self` is same as `user`.

Comment: How do you implement `name_without_title`?

Comment: `attr_accessible :name_without_title` does that.

Comment: also `attr_writer :name_without_title` , more here http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes

Answer (score 0):

You can add a method with the same name with will override the default method.

```
def name
  return "Dr. #{self.name}"
end
```

Or you can create a new method to do that

```
def formal_name
   "Dr. #{self.name}"
end
```

Comment: Your method `name` will raise a `SystemStackError: stack level too deep`

Comment: And if it's Rails than the second method should be a view helper, not an instance method of the model.